# Memory Leak from ImageSource/CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap (while capturing webcam with AForge)

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks, aforge, imagesource

I am trying to output whatever is captured from a webcam to an [`Image` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a WPF window. I am using the [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) library.

Unfortunately, after a few minutes of successful capturing, I am getting an [`OutOfMemoryException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Likewise, as soon as I start capturing, I can see my memory usage rise continuously in the task manager until the moment of the exception (although there have been a few occasions where memory usage kept rising, then steeply dropped back to its original state, and then kept rising again to the point of the exception).

This is my code for the handler of the [`NewFrame` event](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/3c0dd0f0-680a-373a-6518-626f4f29bc7b.htm) of the [`VideoCaptureDevice` class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f4d3c2ba-605c-f066-f969-68260ce5e141.htm) (whose code for converting the [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instance to an [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is largely based on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484754/1430156) by [Sascha Hennig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810106/sascha-hennig)):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

private void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        using (var streamBitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone()) {
            BitmapSource bitmapSourceVideo;

            var hBitmap = streamBitmap.GetHbitmap();
            try
            {
                bitmapSourceVideo = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }
            bitmapSourceVideo.Freeze();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                                                       {
                                                           videoControl.Source = bitmapSourceVideo;
                                                       }));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

*In case you wonder, the call to `eventArgs.Frame.Clone()` seems to be required. Explanations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910874/1430156), and possibly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777256/1430156).*

While trying to isolate the source of the issue, I have commented out various portions of this code until I arrived at this state:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

private void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        using (var streamBitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone()) {
            BitmapSource bitmapSourceVideo;

            var hBitmap = streamBitmap.GetHbitmap();
            try
            {/*
                bitmapSourceVideo = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            */}
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }
            /*
            bitmapSourceVideo.Freeze();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                                                       {
                                                           videoControl.Source = bitmapSourceVideo;
                                                       }));*/
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

(Obviously, this doesn't draw anything to the window, but that is beside the point now.) This version of the method does not feature the memory leak. Removing the comment signs around the statement with the call to [`CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) brings the memory leak back. **What am I missing here?**

There have been various resources about seemingly similar problems, none of which have helped me find a solution:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685504/1430156) assumes I am loading from a URI that I could instead load into a stream.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271982/1430156) seems to assume I am loading the bitmap data directly from a stream that I can access, and likewise, [this blogpost](http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/05/wrappingstream_implementation.html) suggests to create a stream wrapper.
- The [`Freeze`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) solution from [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx) should not apply, as the leak does not change based on whether I comment or uncomment my call to `Freeze`. This is further corroborated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4382056/1430156).
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546121/1430156), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546289/1430156), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4382056/1430156), and [all answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670151/unmanaged-memory-leak) point out that [`DeleteObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) needs to be invoked once the handle obtained from [`GetHbitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is no longer needed. This is also suggested by [this blogpost](http://arbel.net/2008/10/22/improper-use-of-interopbitmap-can-cause-a-memory-leak/). I am already doing that in the code.
- Information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758731/prevent-outofmemoryexception-with-aforge-and-graphics-fromimage-drawimage) suggests I need to dispose of the `Bitmap`, but I am already disposing of any `Bitmap` instance that I create myself, thanks to the `using` block.
- [This forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bf6b9d1-5994-456f-9d60-02604d9802f1/memory-leak-using-hbitmapbitmapsource-conversion?forum=csharpgeneral) sounds vaguely similar, but it ends in an inconclusive way.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: @Tronald: No, I'm afraid I never followed up on this project (and cannot remember anymore what it was about by now).

Comment: Yeah it was a while ago, so figured it was a long shot. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

My instinct tells me that it is something to do with the bitmapSourceVideo being inside the delegate, and therefore creating a closure and not being cleaned up.

**EDIT**

Try

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            videoControl.Source = bitmapSourceVideo;
            bitmapSourceVideo = null;
        }));
```

Comment: I have looked into that, but how exactly am I supposed to clean up a [`BitmapSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It's not [disposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libraRy/system.idisposable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or something. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11950108/1430156) (though it's not accepted ...) implies no further clean-up is necessary.

Comment: Also what happens if you was to wrap this whole method inside a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` Rather than just for the setting of source?

Comment: I can try, though I don't expect anything good to come out of that - in particular, I'd be surprised if I could rely on `eventArgs.Frame` still being around after the event handler has terminated in the thread in which it was invoked.