# Bitmap Graphics CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-management, memory-leaks

I want to display a `Bitmap` in an `Image` container with WPF.

```
private void updateImagePreview()
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    Image Image_Preview;

    while (true)
    {
        gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        Image_Preview.Source = loadBitmap(bmp);
    }
}

[DllImport("gdi32")]
static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);
public BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{
    IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSource bs = null;
    try
    {
        bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                 ip, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                 System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(ip);
    }

    return bs;
}
```

The problem is, that this creates a huge memory leak. The leak occurs on the `CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` call and fills memory while looping till the limit is exceeded. If I don't use that call, then the leak disappears. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: What do you mean with "memory leak"? It keeps references in memory after it should've been destroyed? Or does a single call fill up your memory?

Comment: It keeps references. A single call would work, but the memory leak would be still there.

Comment: Did you see [this exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28952654/1136211)? It has a lot of links, but yet no answer.

Comment: Try an alternative approach: save the bitmap to a MemoryStream and decode a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from that stream (as shown in multiple posts on StackOverflow)

Comment: I tried the approach [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/04/memory_leak_with_bitmapimage_and_memorystream.html), including the wrapper class and it's also leaking memory.

Comment: How about [`BitmapFrame.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615998(v=vs.110).aspx) with `OnLoad` set?

Comment: Tried it, didn't stop leaking either.

Comment: what is the image size here?

Comment: Tested with 1920x1080 px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it somehow, but I don't exactly know how I got rid of that leak. I assume that calling the code that causes the memory leak in a thread somehow fixes that problem. I highly recommend to use the [stream wrapper](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/04/memory_leak_with_bitmapimage_and_memorystream.html) mentioned in the comments, because using only a MemoryStream causes also a memory leak. Anyways, the following is the code that doesn't lead to the mentioned memory leak and works like a charm for me.

```
Timer takeScreen;

// This is a button to start the screen capturing
private void Button_Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int fps = 30;
        takeScreen = new Timer(o => addNewImage(), null, 0, 1000 / fps);
    }

private void addNewImage()
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                Image_Preview.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Image_Preview.Source = loadBitmap(bmp)));
            }
        }
    }

public BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
    {
        BitmapSource bmpf = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WrappingStream ws = new WrappingStream(ms))
            {
                source.Save(ws, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                bmpf = BitmapFrame.Create(ws, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }
        }

        return bmpf;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Freeze()` on your `BitmapSource` before returning it. It seems to help release some references to the image bytes.

```
[DllImport("gdi32")]
static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);
public BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{
    IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSource bs = null;
    try
    {
        bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                 ip, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                 System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(ip);
    }

    bs.Freeze();
    return bs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a memory leak, the first thing that you should check is, if there are any Disposable objects that are not disposed.

I can see that you don't dispose both [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) instances, that could cause memory leaks.

Make sure you dispose them at the end of their usage.

Eg: In `updateImagePreview` method

```
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
   ....
}
```

Eg: In `loadBitmap` method

```
public BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{
    ....

    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(ip);
        source.Dispose();
    }

    return bs;
}
```